# Unix- Python Selenium (webdriver) firefox "Untrusted connection"

Tags: unix, python-2.7, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a python script on a unix machine to do a automated task on firefox. However the browser gives me "This Connection is Untrusted" page, which stops the script.

I tried some of the solution posted by other people but issue did not go away. I am still seeing the "connection untrusted" page.

Here is what I wrote:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
profile.default_preferences["webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer"] = False
profile.update_preferences()

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get('https://172.18.35.172/encadmin/')
```

I tried this and it did not work for some reason. Could it be that I am running the script on a unix machine and I do not have right to use alternative profile on firefox? Is there anyway I can check?